# Error 1 ) expected for add a string in list

Tags: c#, string, list

Why is this error?
How to fix this error?
The semicolons are wrong

```
            List<string> codeForPortal=new List<string>();
        codeForPortal.Add("<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/JsFile/jquery-1-10-1-min.js\"></script>");
```

Comment: I see a lot of un-escaped quotation marks there...

Comment: Not that I know C#, but I suppose you need to escape the inner quotation marks ("), that is, put backslashes (\\) in front of them.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel: The semicolons are wrong

Comment: BTW; are you using a syntax highlighter? Because, if you are, it should make it clear that the string is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape the double quote using `\`:

```
codeForPortal.Add("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://mysite.com/JsFile/jquery-1-10-1-min.js\"></script>");
```

Comment: I believe  your answer is correct and you answered very quickly. I am surprised!

Comment: @Alireza thanks, I consider it as a compliment :)

Answer (score 0):

you need a few "`\`"

```
         List<string> codeForPortal=new List<string>();
         codeForPortal.Add("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://mysite.com/JsFile/jquery-1-10-1-min.js\"></script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not escaping your quotes correctly.

```
codeForPortal.Add("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://mysite.com/JsFile/jquery-1-10-1-min.js\"></script>");
```